# CSS error: why isn't the header horizontally aligning and footer justified to space evenly?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm a coding newbie - using CSS flex box to create a mock responsive layout and I'm having trouble with horizontally aligning the header elements in the widest viewport, and flexing the footer to space-evenly.

For the header, I tried `display:inline` and `text-align:center` with no success. With the footer, I tried `display:flex` and `justify-content: space-evenly` also with no success.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
       <h1>actual image logo here</h1>
       <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
    </div>
    </header>
  <footer>
    <ul class="social">
      <li class="social_icon">Twitter Logo here</li>
      <li class="social_icon">Facebook logo here</i></li>
      <li class="social_icon">Insta logo here</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code, it's hard to say what is wrong without seeing the problem
Maybe use codepen or jsFiddle, or add code snippet here, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style: none;
}
```

If you're willing to use flexbox, you have to add `display: flex` on header. Then center it horizontally with `justify-content: center`.
In footer you have to actually add `display: flex` to your , because that it's children you want to position evenly.

[Here's working example](https://jsbin.com/hociciwese/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

if your header and footer take 100% of the screen width, then do :

```
header,footer {
    width:100%
}
```

Then to align center any element, the easiest way here is with flex box like you thought

```
header {
     background: #aaf;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
   }

footer {
     background: #aff;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    }

header div.logo {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
    }

footer ul.social {
      width : 100%;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
```

Since Header and Footer each have a child (a div for the header and a ul for the footer) you need to, again, use flex to center the content of those children (the h1 and the li).
For the `space-evenly` to work on the `ul` I had to increase its default width otherwise it seems to `fit content` and look centered.
If you have anymore questions don't hesitate to leave a comment.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(36, 36, 33);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

   header,
   footer {
     width: 100%
   }

   header {
     background: #aaf;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
   }

    footer {
     background: #aff;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
    }

    header div.logo {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
    }

     header div.logo > *{
       padding: 0 10px;
     }

    footer ul.social {
      width : 100%;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <div class="logo">
          <h1>actual image logo here</h1>
          <h1>The ABC Company</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
  <footer>
      <ul class="social">
          <li class="social_icon">Twitter Logo here</li>
          <li class="social_icon">Facebook logo here</i></li>
          <li class="social_icon">Insta logo here</li>
      </ul>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The only reason to stick with one `h1` tag was for SEO, but in the HTML5 world, search engines no longer care: https://www.seroundtable.com/google-h1-tags-23699.html Use as many `h1`s as makes sense and looks good.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It seems I was taught a _common misconception_

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
}

.social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```